# Grammatical rule for using has vs. does

Tags: verbs

Last week a young adult from Haiti, enrolled in our ESL class, asked the following question when presented with the following:

Tea has caffeine, and so does coffee.

His question was: "Why can't you use the word "has" in place of "does"?

I had two responses. First of all, I don't believe that a comma is needed because the second clause is not independent. Secondly, I prefer not to use a word twice in a sentence. I know the first use of "has" indicates past, present, and future, but, beyond that, I'm not certain what to tell him.

Greg T.

Comment: First, I think the comma adds to the readability of the sentence.  Secondly, have you tried asking this question on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), since it apparently arises from a Learners' class?

Comment: The comma is an optional orthographic element, not really an aspect of "language use" as such. As to *so **does** coffee* vs *so **has** coffee*, they're both fine (the former being just a reduced form reflecting a hypothetical preceding *Tea **does** have caffeine*).

Comment: The comma actually represents an audible linguistic phenomenon -- the mid-lo-hi-mid intonation sequence over a couple syllables, between which the comma is placed in print. It's optional orthographically because it's optional in speech. However, the important point is that one ***can***, in fact, use _has_ instead of _does_ in this construction.

Comment: @JohnLawler It might sound like a stupid question, but A says "I love you." And B says "So do I". Can B say "So love I"?

Comment: @Rathony: No. It's only possible here with _has_ because (a) the _so_ idiom requires inversion, and (b) _has_ also means 'possess/contain'. This is the sort of exception that develops as the construction gathers usages.

Comment: (BrEng) *Has any drink got caffeine?* A: "Tea has (got) caffeine, and so has coffee" (AmEng) *Do any drinks have caffeine?*  B: "Tea has caffeine, and so does coffee". Both forms are fine. It's like asking: "Do you have a car? OR "Have you got a car?" A: "I have (got) a car, and so has my brother." B: "I have a car, and so does my brother."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is a perfect example of a *dummy verb.* A dummy verb is a type of *auxiliary verb* used in place of another verb. Often used to do exactly what you said: avoid saying the same word twice.

It's often used in answers also:

- Q: "Do you take this man to be..."
- A1: "I take him." Would be awkward, so
- A2: "I do." *Do* is standing in for *take*.

See [this page](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/auxiliary-verb.html) and scroll down to the dummy verb section.

When *does* is used with *have* it does form the emphatic tense, as portcall said. But when the main verb is left out I would say it no longer functions as emphatic tense. The emphatic auxiliary verb is being used as a placeholder for the main verb

Answer (score 1):

@G. Tomevi: Taken alone, "So does coffee." is incomplete, yes. But since it follows a sentence which contains THE complete thought, it becomes complete. Sentences of this construction should normally follow a sentence which contains the complete thought, or part of the whole context.  In this case, "Tea has caffeine." does the job of providing the complete thought.

@Roaring Fish:  This is the part of the original post which contains "does."

"...so does coffee."

Not only is this clause emphatic but it is also inverted (the verb *does* precedes the subject *coffee*).  Moreover, this second clause follows an independent clause (Tea has caffeine) from which it takes meaning to complete the thought.

To construct its non-emphatic form, I have to 'borrow' the thought from the first clause to make it meaningful, and I also have to construct the sentence in normal order (not inverted).  This is the result:
"Coffee has caffeine too."

In the non-emphatic or normal form, a sentence uses only the main verb (in this case, "has"). In the emphatic form, on the other hand, the verb is in the following format:  auxiliary verb + main verb (does + have).

If used together with the first clause it would read this way:
"Tea has caffeine, and coffee has caffeine too."

Notice the redundant use of *has caffeine*. I firmly believe that the reason why the writer of the sentence decided to go for inversion and use the emphatic form in constructing the second clause, as well use ***so*** in place of ***too***, is to avoid redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is correct, but it's also fine to say

> tea has caffeine, but so has coffee.

Now, this isn't a educated grammatical answer, but I think 'do' is working a little like a pronoun. You know the way you can simplify a specific noun with 'it', say, when it's clear what you're referring to?

> Coffee has caffeine. it is bitter.

Notice we're avoiding repeating the noun by using the pronoun as a placeholder.

I think 'do' is acting in a similar way. We know we're talking about 'have'. So you insert the more general 'do' instead of repeating yourself. For 'have' it's not very helpful, but for long verbs?

> Concussion grenades discombobulate people, and alcohol discombobulates them too.

Sounds silly. It's less silly to say

> Concussion grenades discombobulate people, and alcohol does too.

Note that the 'does' also swallows 'them' out of the sentence.

I have no idea whether this is a known thing or nonsense, but it makes sense to me.

Answer (score -3):

**Tea has caffeine, and so does coffee.**

**His question was: "Why can't you use the word "has" in place of "does"?**

The use of 'does' is correct. But you're right, there should be no comma. In fact, if I were to correct the sentence, I would rewrite it as follows:
**Tea has caffeine. So does coffee.**

To better understand why "does" is used instead of "has" (and why it is correct to do so), one needs an understanding of the **emphatic form** of sentences.  Also called *emphatic tense* or *emphatic mood*, it is formed with the use of the present or past tense of the auxiliary verb **do** + **base form of the verb**. The subject sentence, in emphatic form, goes this way (using my revised version):

Tea *does have* caffeine. So *does* coffee [*have*].

(The second sentence is the inverted form of, "Coffee *does have* [coffee] too.")

**To further illustrate, this time using the past tense:**

Simple form:  John **went** to school yesterday too.

Emphatic form:  John **did go** to school yesterday too.

Emphatic, inverted form:  So **did John**.

Comment: This is a clear, lucid response to my question. I will now go investigate more about emphatic form. One question though... So does coffee. Isn't that incomplete because it does not express a complete thought?

Comment: If that is an emphatic 'does' in the OP, could you show us the non-emphatic form of the sentence?

Comment: @G. Tomevi: "So do